# update the next inputs with different ids with the same value

Tags: jquery

here is my code. i am having different ids for input elements and my idea is to update the same value to the all inputs. i am having the idea how to update the all inputs onchange but i need to change the next but not previous. Example suppose if i have 20 inputs if i change the 8th input the value should be updated to all the inputs from 8th to 20th input but the previous 7 inputs should not be changed. i stuck up here how to write the code.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.tc').change(function(){

          var id=$(this).attr("id"); 
          var val=$(this).val();
          var tot=$('.tc').length;


         });    


       });
 </script>
</head>
  <body>
     <?php
         include('connect.php');
          $yr=$_POST['year'];
          $sm=$_POST['sem'];
          $br=$_POST['branch'];
          $k=0;

         $sql="select * from intstd where year='$yr' and sem='$sm' and branch='$br'";
         $query=mysql_query($sql);
         echo"<table>";
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
             $k++;
             echo"<tr>";
             echo"<td>$k</td>";
             echo"<td>". $row['rollno']."</td>";
             echo"<td><input type='text' name='a[]' class='tc' id='$k' /></td>";
             echo"<td><input type='text' name='b[]' id='$k' /></td>";
              echo"</tr>";
            }
           echo"</table>";
          ?>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/6mxo5zu1/

```js
$('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
  var that = this;
  $(this).nextAll('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(that).val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text-1" />
<input type="text" id="text-2" />
<input type="text" id="text-3" />
<input type="text" id="text-4" />
<input type="text" id="text-5" />
<input type="text" id="text-6" />
<input type="text" id="text-7" />
<input type="text" id="text-8" />
<input type="text" id="text-9" />
<input type="text" id="text-10" />
<input type="text" id="text-11" />
<input type="text" id="text-12" />
```

I've 12 `input textbox` with unique `id` attached to it.

One of the textbox value changes then rest of the `input textbox` value will updated **only the next not the previous**.

No need of using `id` over here.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your statement "its not working" is very vague. Can you elaborate what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Just set unique ids for your inputs (let's say, in form like `input_0`, `input_1` etc.) and try loop it like this:

```
for (var i=first_index_to_modify; i<=last_index_to_modify; i++) {
  $('#input_'+i).val('myval');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your inputs are having sequential ids like 1 ,2 ,3, and so on.

you can simply do it this way.

```
var i = 0;
for(i = 1;i <$('.tc').length; i++ ) {
    if ($('.tc')[i].attr('id') >= id) {
        $('.tc')[i].val(val);
    }
}
```